# first vbs checking diskpace on remote servers

Tags: vbscript

error returned from this script:

space.vbs(13,2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found

servers.txt exists and is readable
I can map a drive to any of the servers in servers.txt and check space manually

Unless there is a syntax error in my code, could it be an authentication issue? I'm not sure how to create net use or run as in vbs. Although as I said I can map a drive manually.

The line with an error is apparently 
set d = objfso.GetDrive("\strComputer\c$")

space.vbs query a list of servers and return the free space

```
dim strInputPath, strOutputPath
dim objFSO, objTextIn, objTextOut

strInputPath = "c:\servers.txt" '- location of input
strOutputPath = "c:\output.csv" '- location of output

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objTextIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strInputPath,1 )
set objTextOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile( strOutputPath )

Do until objTextIn.AtEndOfStream = True

    strComputer = objTextIn.ReadLine
    set d = objfso.GetDrive("\\strComputer\c$")
    objTextOut.WriteLine now & "," & strComputer & "," & d.FreeSpace/1073741824

loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. VBScript does not interpolate variables into strings
2. Your computers are probably not all named "strComputer"

So:

```
>> strComputer = "pipapo"
>> WScript.Echo 1, "\\strComputer\c$"
>> WScript.Echo 2, "\\" & strComputer & "\c$"
>>
1 \\strComputer\c$
2 \\pipapo\c$
```

Comment: changing to "\\" & strComputer & "\c$" worked thank you. Also thank you for the troubleshooting tip.